# Remove Entire Row if Column Contains $0.00 Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 columns of data (e.g. A, B and T) and the columns in between B and T are hidden. In column T I have a bunch of numbers in the currency format (e.g. $30,000.00, $18,430.00 and $0.00). My goal is to remove the entire row via `Autofilter` if column T contains $0.00.

I am currently trying the following code and everything is disappearing instead of just the rows that contain $0.00 in T column.

`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$T$500").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="$0.00"`

I am open to other ways of solving this without `Autofilter` as well.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this will solve the issue, but there are a couple of things to note. Firstly if the value is zero, and it's just formatted as a currency, then you should have 0 as your criteria. Secondly, AutoFilter hides the rows that _don't_ fit the criteria. Overall, your criteria should probably be `"<>0"`

Comment: here is a link to [Range.EntireRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff836836.aspx), it will help you solving your problem: